# Created issue templates as mentioned on github but they are not activated somehow

Tags: github, github-issues

The [current project](https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-it-extension/issues) contains the directory: `.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/` and a `bug_report.md` and a `feature_request.md` file inside there. Also I have a `config.yml` file but unfortunately If I try to create an issue none of the templates will be taken into account?

Does someone has a hint/idea what I could have forgotten or made wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Creating an issue template](https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/manually-creating-a-single-issue-template-for-your-repository) mentions

> This is the legacy workflow to create an issue template. We recommend using the upgraded multiple issue template builder to create multiple issue templates.

[The configuration](https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/configuring-issue-templates-for-your-repository#configuring-the-template-chooser) mentions:

> If you used the legacy workflow to manually create an `issue_template.md` file and enable blank issues in your `config.yml` file, the template in `issue_template.md` will be used when people chose to open a blank issue.
> **If you disable blank issues, the template will never be used**.

---

The [OP khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61579138/created-issue-templates-as-mentioned-on-github-but-they-are-not-activated-someho/61580169?noredirect=1#comment108958714_61580169):

> I recreated them.
>
> And the issue was that my templates contained comments which seemed to be a problem or the `config.yml`...This is now working.

---

Starting June 2021, this is evolving:

> ### [Issues forms beta for public repositories](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-06-23-issues-forms-beta-for-public-repositories/)

> Issues submitted to open source projects often lack important information.
>
> Markdown issue templates can help by providing text that contributors can remove and replace with their own input – but sometimes contributors can miss details or get confused.
>
> **New, YAML configured issue forms enable maintainers to build structured forms with required fields and easy-to-follow steps so that they can capture every important detail.**
>
> [image: User submits an issue via issue forms. -- https://i2.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/1469659/122435700-20f37b00-cf90-11eb-8028-056c7449e555.gif]
>
> Issue forms are now available in beta for all publicly accessible repositories.
>
> Learn more about issue forms

Comment: First thanks for you answer but unfortunately I don't have an `issue_template.md` file in my repo I only have as mentioned `bug_report.md` and `feature_request.md` in my repo and as I mentioned `config.yml` in the repo...

Comment: Yes. And interestingly the page for https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-it-extension/community does not show me active templates which shows the problem..?...

Comment: Could you try and recreate them through the Web GUI instead of manually?

Comment: I found the problem. I recreated them. And the issue was that my templates contained comments which seemed to be a problem or the `config.yml`...This is now working. Thanks for you guidance/time.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that if you have any old .md template with the same name as a .yml template it will not shown any repo should you try to make organization default template .